# onInstall() not running when I test my project as add-on on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-apps-script-addon

Should `onInstall` trigger work when I **test** my project as an add-on?

I made a very simple `onInstall` function. It just adds content to a row on the spreadsheet. It should be called when the add-on is installed, but I am now trying to verify this behavior using "Test as add-on" feature.

```
function onInstall(){
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Destinatários").appendRow(['test']);
}
```

Again, If I try to use the menu option "Publish > Test as add-on" the `onInstall` is not being called. Shouldn't it be called? Whats the expected behavior.

I've tried all the "Installation Config" options for the test and it still didn't work on my add-ons test.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing autorisation trouble check what you can do here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#the_complete_lifecycle[image]

Comment: English please. What should the user have done in what order to get the desired result. I have read that documentation multiple times and never intend to publish to marketplace. It is not at all clear how it applies to private addons.